# "stop pattern" vs "stops pattern"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I want to describe the progression of stops of a bus route. I'm wondering whether it's better to call it the "**stop** pattern" or the "**stops** pattern" (or similarly: "**stop** sequence" vs. "**stops** sequence")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'sequence' and a 'pattern' are two different things.

For example, "1, 6, 20, 130" is a *sequence* of numbers, but an entirely random one (I hope - I just made it up). There is no discernable *pattern*.

On the other hand, "2, 4, 8, 16, 32" is also a sequence of numbers, but there *is* a pattern - each number is double the previous value. A 'pattern' is where there is a recognisable, repeating characteristic determining each item in the sequence.

So, if the bus stops along the route are all equidistant (ie the distance between each one is the same) then you could say there is 'a pattern' and describe that. Or, if there were some other 'rule' that determined their placement, such as they were all placed next to a school or a store, you could perhaps say that was the pattern. But if there is no pattern, and you are merely listing the stops, then you are just describing a 'sequence', nothing more.

That said, neither "bus stop pattern" or "bus stop sequence" are idiomatic phrases. A list of stops along with the times buses arrive would normally be called a "*bus timetable*", or a "*schedule*".

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'd like to use the term pattern because I'm looking into a huge collection of data about bus trips and I'm extracting some relevant stop patterns according to some traffic rules (e.g., stops: 1, 5, 900, 12... is a pattern. Boring details omitted). My question is: "stop pattern" or "stop**s** pattern"?

Comment: @floatingpurr If I had to choose one of those, I'd say "stop pattern". But that would be a new, unfamiliar noun phrase that just wouldn't be recognised. Before you use such a term, perhaps you need to make it clear that there is "a pattern in the stops".

Comment: If there were  (perhaps) some buses that called only at certain stops, and skipped others, and some buses that called at all stops, you might call the sequences of stops 'stopping patterns'. The expression is used in connection with railways.